# Android : Views is not showing, and only the background (the viewgroup) is showing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, layout

Here's my problem :

I just created AboutActivity that can be accessed by Menu from the MainActivity.

The problem is, the activity_about doesn't show me the views that consists of 2 Textview and a CircleImageView.

Here's the design view of the activity_about.xml (and preview of the issue) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Rky.png

And these are the codes :

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.amgiwork
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import java.lang.Exception    

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
         private lateinit var rvEmployees: RecyclerView
         private var list: ArrayList<Employee> = arrayListOf()

         override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

             rvEmployees = findViewById(R.id.rv_employees)
             rvEmployees.setHasFixedSize(true)

             list.addAll(EmployeeData.listData)
             showRecyclerList()
         }

         private fun showRecyclerList() {
             rvEmployees.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
             val listHeroAdapter = ListEmployeeAdapter(list)
             rvEmployees.adapter = listHeroAdapter
         }

         private fun showAboutActivity() {
             try {
                 val intent = Intent(this, AboutActivity::class.java)
                 startActivity(intent)
                 finish()
             }
             catch (e: Exception) {
                 Log.w("showAboutActivity", e.message.toString())
             }
         }

         override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
             menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
             return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
         }

         override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
             setMode(item.itemId)
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
         }
         private fun setMode(selectedMode: Int) {
             when (selectedMode) {
                 R.id.action_employee_list -> {
                 }
                 R.id.action_about -> {
                     showAboutActivity()
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

**AboutActivity**

```
     package com.example.amgiwork

     import android.content.Intent
     import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
     import android.os.Bundle
     import android.util.Log
     import android.view.Menu
     import android.view.MenuItem
     import java.lang.Exception

     class AboutActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

         override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_about)

         }

         private fun showMainActivity() {
             try {
                 val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                 startActivity(intent)
                 finish()
             }
             catch (e: Exception) {
                 Log.w("showMainActivity", e.message.toString())
             }
        }

         override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
             menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
             return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
         }

         override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
             setMode(item.itemId)
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
         private fun setMode(selectedMode: Int) {
             when (selectedMode) {
                 R.id.action_employee_list -> {
                     showMainActivity()
                 }
                 R.id.action_about -> {
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

**activity_about.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@color/lightYellow">

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             tools:ignore="UselessParent">

             <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                 android:id="@+id/tv_dev_image"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="190dp"
                 app:civ_border_color="@color/darkRed"
                 app:civ_border_width="5dp"
                 tools:src="@drawable/dev" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tv_dev_name"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:maxLines="2"
                 android:textColor="@color/darkRed"
                 android:textSize="32sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 tools:text="Dyaksa Hanindito" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tv_contact"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:maxLines="2"
                 android:textColor="@color/darkRed"
                 android:textSize="19sp"
                 tools:text="Contact :" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tv_dev_email"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:maxLines="2"
                 android:textColor="@color/darkRed"
                 android:textSize="19sp"
                 tools:text="dyaksa.hanindito@indosatooredoo.com" />
         </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
```

I have tested in on another device, aswell as running the project on another computer and the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only wrong thing here is that you are using `tools` prefix in your layout incorrectly. Change it to `android` in CircleImageView and every TextView and everything will work fine.

Comment: Just changed tools:src="@drawable/dev" to android:src="@drawable/dev" and my app crashes whenever i navigate to the activity (via menu) :(

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.amgiwork, PID: 1519
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.amgiwork/com.example.amgiwork.AboutActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown> . . .

Comment: It looks like ```OutOfMemoryException```, cause, probably, your ```@drawable/dev``` is too big. Try to provide a smaller image and check for results.

Comment: So what was the problem? ;)

Comment: Thx dude!, changed tools: prefixes into android: and shrinked the image source from 900kb to 40kb. Just realized that tools are only labels for helping devs in android studio